# Files in Dropbox Public folder are no longer shown in WebBrowser but it opens dialog to open/save file

Tags: webbrowser-control, dropbox

I have a simple web browser form which only navigates to a specific webpage, however instead of navigating to that webpage, it gives me a prompt to open or save the file, when clicking "Open" it opens in my default web browser, and "Save" let's me save the HTML file.

I don't know what's causing this, so any help is appreciated.

I also assure you that the syntax is correct, and the URL to the HTML file is also correct.

Comment: Show us your code and information on the url you navigate to.

Comment: It's literally WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://linktohtmlfile.com/page.html") - The link is a pseudo link of course. It is a dropbox file, if that helps; it used to work before but I think it's just something with my installation of windows or maybe something I've forgot to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no problem with your code but a specific problem with that URL. Using the URL I got the same problem. Navigating to the URL in Firefox, I was asked to save the file. I saved the file locally and uploaded it to my own Dropbox folder. From there, using the same file name and the same file content, the file was displayed in the browser.

Analysing the http traffic with Fiddler, the http results differ in the following headers.

From your Dropbox account:

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=News.html
content-security-policy: referrer no-referrer; sandbox;
x-content-security-policy: referrer no-referrer; sandbox;
x-webkit-csp: referrer no-referrer; sandbox;
```

From my Dropbox account:

```
content-disposition: inline; filename="News.html"; filename*=UTF-8''News.html
content-security-policy: referrer no-referrer
x-content-security-policy: referrer no-referrer
x-webkit-csp: referrer no-referrer
```

Note the difference between "content-disposition: inline" and "content-disposition: attachment" which makes the browser offer download instead of showing inline in the browser. Also note the additional "Sandbox" in the response from your account.

<s>I see two possible explanations for this different behaviour:</s>

1. (Less probably) Maybe the different accounts are run on two different DropBox servers with different Dropbox Server Software versions.
2. Dropbox maybe has a mechanism to analyse access to public files and identify access patterns that look like they are part of some attack on IT systems. So, maybe Dropbox has put a penalty on your file because it thinks it has identified some dangerous activity going on with it.

Possibility 2 seems to be most probable. Maybe try to rename the file or place it into a different subfolder and contact Dropbox about the issue.

The problem is that Dropbox has disabled inline-display for content hosted on free accounts this month. It still works for my account because I have a paid (Dropbox Pro) account.

Dropbox has the following information [in their documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16):

> Dropbox Basic (free) users: Beginning October 3, 2016, you can no
>   longer use shared links to render HTML content in a web browser. If
>   you created a website that directly displays HTML content from your
>   Dropbox, it will no longer render in the browser. The HTML content
>   itself will still remain in your Dropbox and can be shared. Learn
>   more.
>
> Dropbox Pro and Business users: Beginning September 1, 2017, you can
>   no longer render HTML content.

Comment: This must be it then. Looks like I'll have to find a new host for my html files now.

Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have an alternative approach which would allow you to still use dropbox *and* benefit from your html pages.

[`dboxserver`](https://github.com/sajal/dboxserver) ([written in Go](https://golang.org/))

> Since October 3, 2016 [Dropbox stopped serving html files](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16) with the correct text/html content-type header. .html and .json files are now served with a content-disposition header which makes the browser download the file instead of render it.

Launch your own server with:

```
CLIENT_ID="REMOVED" CLIENT_SECRET="REMOVED" ACCESS_TOKEN="REMOVED" go run server.go -hostname "db.sajalkayan.com"
```

(change the hostname by your own server name)

> You need to create an app at the [Dropbox developer portal](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).
>
> - `CLIENT_ID` - "`App key`"
> - `CLIENT_SECRET` - "`App secret`"
> - `ACCESS_TOKEN` - Allow implicit grant and generate an access token.
> - `hostname` - If configured the server listens over https on `:443` and gets certificate from Let's Encrypt otherwise it listens over http on `:8889`. folder
> - `folder` - Defaults to `/Public`: The Dropbox folder you want to expose.